# Is it possible to hide popover arrow in gtk3?

Tags: gtk

Is it possible to hide popover arrow in gtk3?
gtk4 has https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/unstable/GtkPopover.html#gtk-popover-set-has-arrow

I looked at the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Is this for a menu button? Or another widget?

Comment: it's for another widget

Answer (score 0):

You might use the "gtk_menu_button_set_use_popover" function.  Here is a sample piece of code referencing a GTK menu button named "editbutton".

```
gtk_menu_button_set_use_popover(GTK_MENU_BUTTON(editbutton), FALSE);
```

The result is a menu list that looks like a pop-up without the arrow.

Here is what an illustration of the result of adding that line of code to a sample program of mine.

[image: Example of no pop-up arrow for a menu]

Perhaps that will provide you with the desired display in your program.

Regards.